# plot a trapezoid in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to plot a trapezoid, like this (expertly drawn in Paint):
[image]

When I define the corners and plot though

```
positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep("glass", each = 4),
  x = c(3.5, 6.5, 2, 8),
  y = c(1, 1, 8, 8),
  fill = rep("a")
)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(positions, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = fill, group = id))
```

I get this.  How do I define connections between the corners?
[image]

Comment: P.S. I love the paint skills.

Comment: @IanCampbell thanks, honestly with Paint skills like these I don't even know why I bother with `ggplot`.

I'll accept your answer as soon as the timer expires

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The points are connected in the order of the rows. Simply change the order of the last two points:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(positions[c(1,2,4,3),], aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = fill, group = id))
```

[image]